# Ramifications and Impacts to Users when Detaching TFS Database

Tags: database, tfs, refresh, database-backups

I have a scenario where I have to detach for a backup and then reattach the database from Team Foundation Server 2017. Our database administrator said that there would be an impact to users online that would prevent the detachment from occurring if they were doing a specific activity, can you advise? I have been asked to find out what the users to do and prepare for when we do the detachment. How will this impact the TFS and user processes?

Please advise and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your databases are in use by a Team Foundation Server deployment, use `TfsConfig collection /detach` command line to handle this.

> When you detach a collection, **all jobs and services are stopped, and
>   then the collection database is stopped**. In addition, the detach
>   process copies over the collection-specific data from the
>   configuration database and saves it as part of the project collection
>   database.
>
> This configuration data is what allows the collection database to be
>   attached to a different deployment of Azure DevOps Server. If that
>   data is not present, you cannot attach the collection to any
>   deployment of Azure DevOps Server except the one from which it
>   originated.

Note: Detaching a collection prevents users from accessing any projects in that collection. Basically, it will not influence others working on other project collection in TFS server.

You could also take a look at a detail process and explanation about [Detach the collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-project-collection?view=azure-devops#1-detach-the-collection) from UI and [tfconfig command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd?view=azure-devops#collection) from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're mentioning your database administrator I'm guessing that there is a fundamental confusion occurring here. Let me explain:

Detaching is a concept in both SQL Server and TFS. In SQL Server it means that you are removing a database from SQL Server without actually deleting the files that make up this database (.mdf, .ndf, .ldf files). Once a database is detached you can attach it again by pointing it to the files that made up the database (ususally just the .mdf).

In TFS you can also detach. But there you detach Team Project Collections (TPC). A TPC is a concept that maps directly down to a SQL Server database, i.e. for every TPC that you host on TFS you'll find a corresponding SQL Server database. Detaching a TPC means that TFS will no longer have any reference to it, it no longer is aware that it exists. However, you can attach a TPC to TFS again by pointing it to the corresponding SQL Server database.

The question now is what exactly you want to detach, an SQL Server database or a TFS TPC. Note that if you want to detach an SQL Server database that is attached as TPC on TFS you *must* first detach that TPC from TFS before you detach the database from SQL Server.

Note also that TFS's detach operation is notoriously unreliable. Believe me, it is, I know it from experience. You can save yourself lots of detach related problems if you reboot the TFS application tier host server before you actually detach a TPC from TFS.

For the end user the impact of detaching a TPC from TFS is simply that the end user will no longer be able to access that TPC. So, there is nothing that the end user must know except of course being aware of the downtime that you need to communicate to the users.